# Multiple input items with dynamic disabling in React/Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to make multiple input boxes in a list item in React native. The condition is that a user can input in only 1 rows.

For ex:

-Input box 1    Input box2

> ```
>     Input box 1.   Input box2
>     Input box 1.   Input box2
> ```

The above is the sample layout. The condition is user can input in any of the line items. But if the user enters in **Input box1** in 1st row then Input box in 2nd and 3rd row should be disabled.

or if he/she enters in 2nd then 1st and 3rd **Input box 1** should be disabled.

I am not sure how to implement this logic

Comment: Did you happen to solve your problem? If the answer helped please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I wrote based on your explanation:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [disabledRow, setDisabledRow] = useState(0);
  const [values, setValues] = useState(['', '', '', '']);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    // Get the row attribute so we can know which row the user is chaning.
    const row = parseInt(event.target.dataset.inputRow || '10', 10);
    // Get the input Id so we will change the corresponding value in 'values' state.
    const inputId = parseInt(event.target.dataset.inputId || '0', 10);

    // Change the corresponding value in state.
    values[inputId] = event.target.value;
    setValues([...values]);

    // Disabled the other row
    if (row === 1) {
      setDisabledRow(2);
    } else {
      setDisabledRow(1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {/* Row 1 */}
        <input
          data-input-row={1}
          data-input-id={0}
          disabled={disabledRow === 1}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={values[0]}
        />
        <input
          data-input-row={1}
          data-input-id={1}
          disabled={disabledRow === 1}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={values[1]}
        />
      </div>
      {/* Row 2 */}
      <div>
        <input
          data-input-row={2}
          data-input-id={2}
          disabled={disabledRow === 2}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={values[2]}
        />
        <input
          data-input-row={2}
          data-input-id={3}
          disabled={disabledRow === 2}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={values[3]}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```